# iOS Swift circle chart

Tags: swift, charts

Any suggestion how to implement the following progress chart for iOS Swift?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just break this down into individual steps.

The first question is how to draw the individual tickmarks.

One way is to draw four strokes using a `UIBezierPath`:

- a clockwise arc at the outer radius;
- a line to the inner radius;
- a counter-clockwise arc at the inner radius; and
- a line back out to the outer radius.

Turns out, you can skip the two lines, and just add those two arcs, and then close the path and you’re done. The `UIBezierPath` will add the lines between the two arcs for you. E.g.:

```swift
let startAngle: CGFloat = 2 * .pi * (CGFloat(i) - 0.2) / CGFloat(tickCount)
let endAngle: CGFloat = 2 * .pi * (CGFloat(i) + 0.2) / CGFloat(tickCount)

// create path for individual tickmark

let path = UIBezierPath()
path.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: outerRadius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
path.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: innerRadius, startAngle: endAngle, endAngle: startAngle, clockwise: false)
path.close()

// use that path in a `CAShapeLayer`

let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.fillColor = …
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath

// add it to our view’s `layer`

view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

Repeat this for `i` between `0` and `tickCount`, where `tickCount` is `90`, and you have ninety tickmarks:

[image]

Obviously, use whatever colors you want, make the ones outside your progress range gray, etc. But hopefully this illustrates the basic idea of how to use `UIBezierPath` to render two arcs and fill the shape for each respective tick mark with a specified color.

---

For example:

```swift
class CircularTickView: UIView {
    var progress: CGFloat = 0.7 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }

    private var shapeLayers: [CAShapeLayer] = []
    private let startHue: CGFloat = 0.33
    private let endHue: CGFloat = 0.66
    private let outOfBoundsColor: UIColor = .lightGray
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        shapeLayers.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperlayer() }
        shapeLayers = []
        
        let outerRadius = min(bounds.width, bounds.height) / 2
        let innerRadius = outerRadius * 0.7
        let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        let tickCount = 90
        
        for i in 0 ..< tickCount {
            let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            shapeLayer.fillColor = color(percent: CGFloat(i) / CGFloat(tickCount)).cgColor
            shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            
            let startAngle: CGFloat = 2 * .pi * (CGFloat(i) - 0.2) / CGFloat(tickCount)
            let endAngle: CGFloat = 2 * .pi * (CGFloat(i) + 0.2) / CGFloat(tickCount)
            
            let path = UIBezierPath()
            path.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: outerRadius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
            path.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: innerRadius, startAngle: endAngle, endAngle: startAngle, clockwise: false)
            path.close()
            shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
            
            layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
            shapeLayers.append(shapeLayer)
        }
    }

    private func color(percent: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
        if percent > progress {
            return outOfBoundsColor
        } 
        
        let hue = (endHue - startHue) * percent + startHue
        return UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: 1, brightness: 1, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

Clearly, you will want to tweak as you see fit. Perhaps change the color algorithm. Perhaps have it start from 12 o’clock rather than 3 o’clock. Etc. The details are less important than groking the basic idea of how you add shape layers with paths to your UI.

---

While I prefer to use shape layers, you can also use a rendition that overrides `draw(_:)`, instead:

```swift
class CircularTickView: UIView { 
    var progress: CGFloat = 0.7 { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }

    private let startHue: CGFloat = 0.33
    private let endHue: CGFloat = 0.66
    private let outOfBoundsColor: UIColor = .lightGray
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        
        let outerRadius = min(bounds.width, bounds.height) / 2
        let innerRadius = outerRadius * 0.7
        let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        let tickCount = 90
        
        for i in 0 ..< tickCount {
            let startAngle: CGFloat = 2 * .pi * (CGFloat(i) - 0.2) / CGFloat(tickCount)
            let endAngle: CGFloat = 2 * .pi * (CGFloat(i) + 0.2) / CGFloat(tickCount)
            
            let path = UIBezierPath()
            path.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: outerRadius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
            path.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: innerRadius, startAngle: endAngle, endAngle: startAngle, clockwise: false)
            path.close()

            if path.cgPath.intersects(UIBezierPath(rect: rect).cgPath)) {
                color(percent: CGFloat(i) / CGFloat(tickCount))
                    .setFill()
                path.fill() 
            }
        }
    }

    private func color(percent: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
        if percent > progress {
            return outOfBoundsColor
        } 
        
        let hue = (endHue - startHue) * percent + startHue
        return UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: 1, brightness: 1, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rob's answer is great!

NSView version:

```
class CircularTickView: NSView {
    var progress: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay(NSRect())
        }
    }

    private var shapeLayers: [CAShapeLayer] = []
    private let startHue: CGFloat = 0.33
    private let endHue: CGFloat = 0.66
    
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
        
        shapeLayers.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperlayer() }
        shapeLayers = []
        
        let outerRadius = min(bounds.width, bounds.height) / 2
        let innerRadius = outerRadius * 0.7
        let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        let tickCount = 90
        
        for i in 0 ..< tickCount {
            let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            shapeLayer.fillColor = color(percent: CGFloat(i) / CGFloat(tickCount)).cgColor
            shapeLayer.strokeColor = NSColor.clear.cgColor
            
            let startAngle = 360.0 - 360.0 / (CGFloat(tickCount * 2)) * CGFloat(i * 2)
            let endAngle = 360.0 - 360.0 / (CGFloat(tickCount * 2)) * CGFloat(i * 2 + 1)
            
            let path = NSBezierPath()
            path.appendArc(withCenter: center, radius: outerRadius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
            path.appendArc(withCenter: center, radius: innerRadius, startAngle: endAngle, endAngle: startAngle, clockwise: false)
            
            path.close()
            shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
            
            layer?.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
            shapeLayers.append(shapeLayer)
        }
    }

    private func color(percent: CGFloat) -> NSColor {
        if percent > progress {
            return .lightGray
        }
        let hue = (endHue - startHue) * percent + startHue
        return NSColor(hue: hue, saturation: 1, brightness: 1, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are going to implement `draw(_:)`, rather than adding `CAShapeLayer`s, you should just `fill` the Bézier paths. I’ve added a UIKit rendition of that in my answer to illustrate the pattern. But the point is that `draw(_:)` is for rendering a view, not for adding layers to the view hierarchy.